Preventing hibernation muscle atrophy with electrical impulses
So I saw a link to this article in a different question, regarding how to keep hibernating humans from turning into bags of jelly via electric neuroimpulses.
My question is, what would this look like? If hibernating space colonists where laid in glass coffins, would an observer see their bodies constantly spasming and/or thrashing? Would this apply to their eyelids/fingers too, so that it would appear almost as if they were actually awake and being tortured?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I can tell you exactly what this looks like. I had a skiing accident as a teen that put me in a leg cast (no weight on my knee) for 18 months. The cast had been cut to allow attachment of electrodes to minimize atrophy. Half a dozen electrodes with wires connected to a controller the size of a transistor radio.
For the record, it's mighty uncomfortable. Turned high enough to actually minimize atrophy, it hurts. Turned up high enough, it burns. Literally. At least it did decades ago when I went through it.
Yes, you can see muscles contracting (not spasming, that's an uncontrolled condition that can affect muscles in damaging ways). But that depends on...

Which muscles we're talking about. Small muscles would be hard to see contract. The primary move-a-bag-of-concrete muscles (e.g. biceps) would be easy to see.

Whether or not you're trying to make the universal decision between life and lifestyle. Keeping a bodybuilder well built takes a whomping amount of stimulus (I know because of the experience trying to keep my previously athletic calves somewhat athletic). Keeping your muscles useful takes a LOT less stimulus.


By the end of the 18 months I was able to move around with one leg and crutches. Consequently, when the cast came off, one leg looked like Arnold Schwarzenegger's and the other like Pee Wee Herman's.
You need to make some worldbuilding decisions
You're applying today's technology to a world capable of sending a colony ship into space for eighteen years. I call that a technology dichotomy. Science would have found a better way to preserve muscles (or I hope it would have) by that time. Electrical stimulus has some dramatic limitations. You can't stimulate every muscle without inserting electrodes into the body in a lot of places. Is the body weightless? I hope so or you can't have significant stimulus anywhere on the back where weight will, over that much time, damage things (including the body). I can't even imagine using this kind of stimulus on a person's tongue, much less throat muscles, muscles used for breathing and digestion (which would result in other problems, like the need to remove periodic waste no matter how deep the hibernation).
I therefore invite you to dream and dream big. To quote Arthur C. Clarke:

The only way of discovering the limits of the possible is to venture a little way past them into the impossible.

So let's look at what we have to work with:

You want a controlled hibernation.
You want the ability to periodically exercise every muscle, including the heart.
No muscle does what it does independently. Everything is tied into the nervous system.

You don't want external electrical stimulus. That's so 2024! But you do want something removable. So I'm voting for sub-micron nerve taps at the base of the skull (a bit Matrix-esque) but on the a side rather than the back so the patient can lie back at their leisure. The nerve tap acts like a couple of sub-nervus (smaller than a nerve) diodes are connected, prohibiting feedback to the brain. Connect a computer and voilà, you have control of the muscles (even the ability to accept feedback like the brain) and the ability to systemically exercise the muscles and preserve the body.
Something like that, maybe.

It could actually be an interesting bit of lore that in stasis your body does atrophy even with electrical stimulation. So you go in looking normal and come out more frail, which is what discourages people from using stasis frequently.
Its an inherent trade off that balances how OP stasis tech is.

@ChellCPlus That's not a bad idea. Electrical stimulation didn't keep my muscles as athletic as they were before the cast. One could say that they kept the muscles usable, but not in condition. Part of that might be due to the impossibility of stimulating all the muscles, but the reality is that forcing a muscle to contract is very different from using a muscle to lift or move weight. That could play into a story quite well.

Aside from @JBH 's excellent answer, consider that electrostimulation alone cannot take the muscle through its entire length of contraction (unless you want the hibernate person to backflip off the hibernation pod). All it can do is to make the muscle tense and untense in the prone position, which is only a fraction of its required range of motion. its an equivalent of doing a 1 milometer bicep curl, instead of curling your arm all the way back and forth. Using nothing but electrodes for months on end will probably preserve at least some muscle fiber, but will not prevent the muscle from shortening considerably, and turn the person into a stiff mannequin that cannot do a sit-up or touch their own nose. Better than becoming quadriplegic from muscular atrophy, but still not ideal.

hmm. so if the hibernation pod was more of a hibernation chamber... and in zero-g...

+1, I just made this point to a comment to my answer - and it's important.
